# Unable to install iOS app made using Air 3.2 on iPad retina

Tags: ipad, flash, air, installation

I am working on Air 3.2 for iOS project . I am making a game. I have made sure to put the UDID of two devices , my iPad 2 and my iPad 4 retina in the mobile provision.

I am able to install the app on my iPad 2 using iTunes but i am unable to install it on iPad 4.

This is the error i am getting.

http://puu.sh/303Bj.jpg ( link to screenshot)

Unable to install error is comming

the app is made in flash professional CS6

on windows system

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you entered the iPad2 to the member center first
Downloaded the mobile provision and certificate
and then entered the iPad4 to the member center?

Try to revoke certificate and redownload
or just redownload it and the mobile provision....